Kunen lemma 1.13 chapter, V.
In Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs" we are given the following:

Let $G:A \to B$ be a $1$-$1$ map which is an isomorphism for the $\in$-relation; then


(1) $\forall m,n\ \forall x \in A^n(s \in \text{En}(m,A,n) \leftrightarrow G \circ s \in \text{En}(m,B,n))$.


(2) $A \equiv B$.

The proof (sketch) is as follows:

(1) is by induction on $n$, and (2) is the special case of (1) when $m = 0$.

It seems like this is a typo, and it should be " $\ldots$ special case when $n = 0$" for (2). I also am unsure if $\forall x \in A^n$ should really be $\forall s \in A^n$.
The proof of (1) is according to Kunen by induction on $n$. I have divided the proof in the inductive step depending on what $m$ is. When $m$ is $2^i \cdot 3^j$ or $2^i \cdot 3^j \cdot 5$, I claim it follows directly from the fact that $G$ preserves the $\in$-relation. But I am having trouble showing that it holds when $m = 2^i \cdot 3^j \cdot 5^{k}$ for $k = 2,3,4$, so that $$\text{En}(m,A,n+1) = A^{n+1} \setminus{\text{En}(i,A,n+1)} \lor \text{En}(m,A,n+1) = \text{En}(i,A,n+1) \cap \text{En}(j,A,n+1) \lor \text{En}(m,A,n+1) = \text{Proj}(A,\text{En}(i,A,n+1),n)$$ for the $\rightarrow$ direction (or the other direction, for that matter). I don't see how to apply the inductive assumption. Any hints and/or clarification would be helpful.
